# qt creator issue when include std string library

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, stdstring

I have this function. I created it with libxml2 and std::string library.

```
#ifndef KNIHOVNA_H
#define KNIHOVNA_H
#include <string>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

std::string hledaniString(int index,xmlDocPtr sharedString)
{
std::string Istring;
xmlAttrPtr attr;

 xmlChar *attrValue;
    xmlNodePtr nodeLevel1 = sharedString->children;
int maxValue;
int aIndex;


attr = xmlHasProp(nodeLevel1, (const xmlChar*)"uniqueCount");
if (attr !=NULL)
    {
        attrValue = xmlGetProp(nodeLevel1, (xmlChar *)"uniqueCount");

    }
    else return "Chybny format souboru. Spatny soubor sharedStrings.xml.";

nodeLevel1 = nodeLevel1->children;

maxValue = atoi((const char *) attrValue);
xmlFree(attrValue);
if (maxValue<=index) return "Chybny format souboru. Spatny soubor sharedStrings.xml.";

for (aIndex = 0;aIndex < index; aIndex++ )
{
nodeLevel1 = nodeLevel1->next;
}
nodeLevel1 = nodeLevel1->children;
attrValue = xmlNodeGetContent(nodeLevel1);
xmlFree(attrValue);
attrValue = xmlNodeGetContent(nodeLevel1);
Istring = (char *) attrValue;
xmlFree(attrValue);
    return Istring;

#endif // KNIHOVNA_H
```

I use it in Code Block project where is everything ok and in qt creator project where I get these errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/string:38: In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:38:0,
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_relops.h:-1: In function 'std::string getString(int, xmlDocPtr)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_relops.h:67: error: expected '=' before '__attribute__'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_relops.h:67: error: expected identifier before '__attribute__'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_relops.h:67: error: expected ';' before '__attribute__'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_relops.h:67: error: expected primary-expression before '__attribute__'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_relops.h:67: error: expected ';' before '__attribute__'
/home/daffy/qt projektz/revize/main.cpp:15: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: You probably have some typo in that file or in some headers you included. Could you post the entire file or is it too big?

Comment: ok, i rewrite my post.

Comment: You are missing a `}` at the end. Put it there and try again.

Comment: omg thank you. If I had to look on my own i never found it.

Comment: When you get ridiculous errors like this, **syntactic** errors pointing to standard headers, then it is probably a missing `}` or some other tiny slip.